# UITableView estimated height non visible cells update

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I am using `UITableView` estimated height functionality. I want make animation to show hints for `textField`. My cell xib file looks like:

[image: TextField cell]

I configured auto-sizing with code below

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

When you first time reach screen it shows only `UITextField` inside cell because `label.text = nil;` when user taps on help button I switch to tips mode and fill labels with some text. 
To update cells I am using

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

But it updates only visible cells. When I scroll to top you can see lags, probably calculation of new height.
How to make force update for all cells with animation?